# Target screen readers and avoid duplicating content

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have heard of `@media speech`, `aural`, `screen` but when I try to play with them in order to have NVDA read a piece of HTML the way I want it to, it doesn't work.

Practical example: in a list of extensions, I want the screen reader to utter "o g g" when reading "ogg", (because otherwise it sounds like "ag"), but I don't want visual users to read a long list of acronyms in capital letters (which is what sounds best) because it is harder to read.

The markup which achieves the expected result is the following.

```
<abbr>
    <span aria-hidden="true">oga</span>
    <span class="screen-reader-only">OGA</span>
</abbr>
```

You can tell I have duplicated the content and there is a lot of boilerplate.

Instead, I would have liked to do the following

```
<abbr>oga</abbr>

@media speech {
  abbr {
     text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

or

```
abbr {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen{
  abbr {
     text-transform: lowercase;
  }
}
```

(by the way, I'm not sure if `@media screen` is a condition which validates if the device has a screen or if it allows a set of instructions to be targetted at the rendering engine)

I have also tried the following, which is less verbose

```
<abbr aria-label="OGA">oga</abbr>

<span aria-label="OGA">oga</span>
```

But none of these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don't need to do anything.

Screen reader users will read an extension a letter at a time with their screen reader if it is a list of abbreviations and they can't understand what is being said.

For example in NVDA they would press <kbd>NVDA</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to read the next letter one at a time.

There are hundreds of hacks you could use (wrap each letter in a `<p>` tag and make it display inline) but they all end up in a mess of completely useless HTML that is semantically incorrect.

### If you absolutely MUST control the speech.

In your example the best way to achieve this is to duplicate your list with one for screen readers and one for visual presentation.

I would 'recommend' (I don't recommend it at all, but it is the best option if you really really must) this approach because:-

1. Much easier to maintain.
2. Same amount of nodes (well + 1 for the additional `<ul>`)  e.g. `<li>`, `<abbr>`, `<span>`, `<span>` VS `<li>`, `<abbr>` times two.
3. Easier to render for the browser (if this was 10,000 items you would notice a difference).
4. Less page weight - saves around 40 bytes per item.
5. Clean HTML without hundreds of `aria` attributes.
6. Other solutions such as relying on CSS media queries etc. may not work with older screen readers (this solution is robust).

#### Example

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line */
}
```

```html
<ul aria-hidden="true">
    <li>
         <abbr>oga</abbr>
    </li>
    <li>
         <abbr>abc</abbr>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="visually-hidden">
    <li>
         <abbr>OGA</abbr>
    </li>
    <li>
         <abbr>ABC</abbr>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Edit

In my comment I realised another option could be to have a toggle button at the start of the list 'capitalise extensions'.

You could then use JavaScript to capitalise the letters (replace the HTML, CSS capitalisation is not robust for screen readers as some ignore it) if someone preferred that, although this is just an idea to leave the markup clean. You would have to test this.

Comment: Can I infer from your answer that there is no clean way to do this? You make a lot of fair points but at the end of the day there are two versions of the same content, for something which remains style issue (separation of concerns), although quite disabling when you have a lot of extensions to read through.

Comment: It isn't a style issue though, you are attempting to offer a different experience to screen reader users and to non screen reader users (albeit with good reason). Screen reader users are used to strange pronunciations of abbreviations and so the first part of the answer is the essential part, you do not really need to do anything. Only other thing you could possibly do is add a toggle button for screen reader users to make the abbreviations capitalised via JavaScript. No matter what you do you are going to have to use a 'hack' to make this work and the above is the cleanest I could think of.

Comment: I like how your last option answers the original question in an unexpected way. I understand the stress you put on the first part of your answer but I don't like how it maintains the status quo on the matter. It turns out there is a CSS speech module with a speak-as property and a spell-out value, but if we stop at "Screen reader users are used to strange pronunciations", it is just never going to be implemented, even though it would be a lot cheaper for synthesiser editors to implement than solving this issue directly (which is as old as the abbr tag).

Comment: yeah there are slow improvements in the speech reader tech sadly (mainly because they spend more time developing fixes for poor markup that we cause as developers than implementing new features). If we had more devs like you trying to go the extra mile it would all happen a lot faster :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [zero-width space char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) : `&#8203;` to separate each char, without making any visual difference

```html
Use the "o&#8203;g&#8203;g" extension
```

- The `aria-label` won't work for [text elements](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/7807).
- `speech` and `aural` media type have no support
- There's no guarantee that uppercase word will be read differently than lowercase. This [depends on the synthesiser](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/4520)

Comment: I don't know how a braille display would render this. I take note of your input on synthesiser differences. On that matter: your hack does not work with mine (it still reads "ag").

Comment: @geoffrey Can you test adding empty `<span />` between the chars?

Comment: It has no effect. I must correct my first comment: eSpeak NG pronounces `o&#8203;g&#8203;g` as "o g g" (When trying to read letter by letter though, it says "symbol 2 0 0 g" each time it encounters `&#8203;`). It pronounces "og" when trying to read `OGG`. Microsoft API version 5 and One Core voices always pronounce "ag" (when trying to read letter by letter, they don't say anything when they encounter `&#8203;`). Note that I am using French voices. I have the feeling that Microsoft API version 5 and One Core try to pronounce "ogg" with an English accent, which adds to the confusion.